# How to get all dialog messages in QuickBlox

Tags: quickblox-android

I am using Quickblox and trying to get all dialog messages, but the number of messages in response are limited (100 by default according to documentation).
How can I get All dialog messages from the server without a limit?

Answer (score 0):

Not absolutely sure but per QB JS SDK, we can set the limit/filter to `NULL` like

```
var filters = null;
QB.chat.dialog.list(filters, function(err, resDialogs) { ... }
```

On the same line, try setting it `NULL` or `0` in your case like

```
QBRequestGetBuilder requestBuilder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
requestBuilder.setLimit(0); <-- Here

QBChatService.getChatDialogs(null, requestBuilder, new QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBDialog>>() {
```

**Disclaimer: I have used QB JS SDK not Android but should be same for all to be consistent I believe.

Comment: requestBuilder.setLimit(0);
return 100 entries by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can set pagination for it, or Quickblox says :

```
Limit search results to N records. Useful for pagination. Default value - 100
```

you can pass N no of limits,before that you have to find the total count of messages of dialog.